# Change \itemize bullet point after certain slide in nestled \itemize environment

Tags: latex, beamer

I want to change the bullet point symbol of certain items in my list after a certain slide.

A solution to a similar problem, but without nestled `\itemize` environments, was posted here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424011/change-beamer-itemize-symbol-and-overlay

The list looks like this:

```
\documentclass[9pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\newenvironment{redenv}{\only{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=red}}}{}

\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-|red@3-> Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2-|red@3-> Item 3
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item 4
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I want to change the symbol for `Item 1` and `Item 3` after a certain pause. This solution works only for `Item 1`, but not `Item 3`.

Edit:

Turns out I copied the example wrongly here, but not in my actual document. Instead I found the real culprit: My document uses a beamercolor.sty sheet that defines the color of the bullet points:

```
\setbeamercolor{item}{parent=local structure}
\setbeamercolor{subitem}{parent=item, fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{subsubitem}{parent=subitem}
```

So, when I delete the `fg=gray`, it works as indended. But I want the gray color as default and only change the color in places I choose. How can reconcile both coloring methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `fg=` in your colour definition:

```
\documentclass[9pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\newenvironment{redenv}{\only{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=red}}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-|red@3-> Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2-|red@3-> Item 3
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item 4
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you don't mind that the text also changes colour, you could use `alert`:

```
\documentclass[9pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-|alert@3-> Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2-|alert@3-> Item 3
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item 4
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```